# How can I edit my meta Superuser profile on the meta.superuser website?

Tags: support, user-profiles

The link `"click here to edit"` on my meta Superuser profile seems not to work at all. The same link on my main Superuser account opens the profile edit screen.

[image]

If the link `click here to edit` on the meta page does not work at all what is it then for???

Answer (score 2):

Your meta profile is linked to the main page, as is your rep and other things. Editing your main page will edit your meta page.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Changes in your profile on the main page does not directly cause changes in your profile on the meta page. If they do, it takes some time. And one question still remains: what is this "dead" link on the meta page for??? But anyway I found something else: type something for your "real name" in your profile -> save it -> logout & login -> change your "real name" -> save it -> logout & login -> delete your "real name" -> save it -> logout & login -> you will see your first entry for "real name" ;-). There is definitely something wrong with the profile savings.

Comment: @mallin It's probably just delayed due to caching. Reputation is out of sync a short time after changes as well.